# Structural breaks panel data

Tags: panel-data, trend

I wanted to ask how to test for say time trend breaks in a panel data with 100 ids and 14 years (2001-2014) worth of data due to an incident. The particular incident happened in 2010 so I wanted to look at whether there was a change in the time trend of the outcome variable $y_{dt}$ pre and post 2010.

Would the following regression work?
$Y_{dt} = \alpha_{d} + \beta t + \beta_{2010} D_{2010} + \varepsilon_{dt}$ wherer $D_{2010}$ is a  dummy taking value 1 for all years after 2010 and 0 before that.

I am suspecting that there is perfect collinearity here which makes it invalid!
Any comments will be helpful.

Comment: Dummy variable regression discontinuity tests such as this summarize so many confounding and/or endogenous issues as to make conclusive inference difficult, if not impossible. One thing that would bolster the credibility of your analysis would be to do the test on HAC and detrended errors. Additional things that might help would be to read up on sequential analysis (e.g., Tartakovsky's book of that title) or the extensive literature on regression discontinuity.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply! I will look HAC and detrended errors up! But my aim here is not to make any causal inference by a simple trend break as such but to see if there is anything discernible visually. Specifically do you have any comments  and concerns on the regression specification?

Comment: Your specification makes sense once the data is whitened and detrended.